# keep text on the right side of an image

Tags: css

I have code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7JhN/). In this code, as it can be seen that there is a div tag with class image and text is appeared on the right side. As there is a lot of text and some of the text is visible on the right and some is below the image tag. **I want this text to be appeared on the right side no matter how much text is there.**

**How can I achieve this?**

```
<div class="image"></div>
<p class="text">adsadas Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare. adsadas Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare viverra erat vel ornare.</p>
```

css

```
.image {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to give your paragraph a `margin-left` based on the `width` of your image:

```
margin-left: 110px;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7JhN/1/